# Converter banco MySQL de latin1 para utf8

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados MySQL que está atualmente definido com charset latin1. Quando faço um select em uma tabela, por exemplo:

```
SELECT nome FROM acolhidos
```

Os caracteres acentuados aparecem dessa maneira:

```
ALESSANDRO ROGÃ‰RIO MOTA DA SILVA
DANIEL MENDONÃ‡A NOVAES
JOSÃ‰ SILVA ARAUJO
```

Então, se eu preciso rodar um select no PHP, por exemplo:

```
$nome = '%JOSÉ%';    

$sql = "SELECT nome FROM acolhidos WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'";

$query = @mysqli_query($conn->link, $sql);
```

O José não vai aparecer no resultado da query, porque ficou gravado no banco como JOSÃ‰

Existe alguma função que converta a minha variável $nome, de forma que os caracteres acentuados fiquem nesse formato: JOSÃ‰ , ROGÃ‰RIO etc, e assim o select acima possa trazer os nomes com caracteres acentuados no resultado da pesquisa?

Mas caso não haja essa função, que resolveria o meu problema de maneira mais simples... como eu poderia converter o conteúdo de todo o meu banco de dados para utf8?

Eu tentei usando o comando:

```
ALTER DATABASE `bancodedados` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Porém, após rodar o comando acima, os caracteres acentuados continuam aparecendo dessa forma:"JOSÃ‰" etc - ou seja - não foram convertidos para "JOSÉ" etc.

Há algum outro comando no MySQL que eu poderia rodar além deste, para fazer a conversão diretamente no banco de dados?

Esta é a configuração atual do banco de dados:

```
show variables like '%character%'    

character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: latin1
character_set_filesystem: binary
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: latin1
character_set_system: utf8
character_sets_dir: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/

show variables like 'collation%'

collation_connection: utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database: latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server: latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Depois de conectar ao banco tente usar: **mysqli_query($conexao,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");**

Comment: Antes você precisa entender se o problema é a conversão ou se é o ambiente cliente. Só tome cuidado pois são 2 situações: uma é trocar a definição para UTF (sem mexer nos dados), a outra é realmente converter linha a linha. Teria que olhar (por exemplo visualizando em hexadecimal) o valor real dos campos para determinar a melhor ação. Se os dados estiverem corretos e a definição errada, só tem que mudar a definição. Fico pensando, não seria mais simples trabalhar em latin no PHP em vez de converter? Nem todo mundo precisa de UTF. Principalmente línguas ocidentais.

Comment: Para a conversão da base, você pode utilizar o software HeidiSQL, você pode alterar todas as definições nas propriedades da base de dados, ele possui um script próprio para isso. Para os dados, a última versão que eu utilize (dois anos atrás), não tinha suporte. Talvez agora possua.

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado pelos comentários de todos!

Eu consegui resolver o problema apenas incluindo 'collate latin1_swedish_ci' ao final do select:

$sql = "SELECT nome FROM acolhidos WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%' collate latin1_swedish_ci";